# G Suite list of calendars per user

Tags: google-calendar-api, google-workspace

I have a G Suite setup, with a couple of calendars and users added to those calendars. Is there a way to retrieve a list of calendar ids per user (where they have access to)? So I can add those calendars per user in our new to developed system.

Answer (score 0):

There are two things you can do:

1. Use the method [Acl;list](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/acl/list) to retrieve for each calendar the respective
   scopes and roles of users/ groups/ domains
2. Use a [service account](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/service-accounts) to [impersonate](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ServiceAccount) subsequently all users of interest and [list](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/calendarList/list) their calendars on their behalf.